# Jquery preload images then show div - animation choppy

Tags: jquery

I have a page that I get the detail images for a classified ad via an Ajax call, then preload the images, add them to the div holder, then show() the div.  For some reason, the animation is really choppy?  Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
$(".showPixFeature.hidden").live('click', function () { 
    var adID = this.id.split('_');
    $("#" + adID[0] + '_' + adID[1]);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../classifieds/classAdPics.php",
    data: "ID="+ this.id,
    success: function(r) {
        var images = r.split('~');
        var thumbs = '';
        var thumbImages = '';

        $.loadImages('../images/35.gif', function() {$('<img />').attr({
            src:'../images/35.gif',
            id:'loader'
        })
        .appendTo("#" + adID[0] + '_' + adID[1]);

        $('#loader').remove();
    });

    var i=0;
    if(((images.length) - 1) > 1){
        for (i=1;i<=(images.length) - 1;i++)
            {
            thumbs = thumbs + '<img src="../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '_sm.jpg" id="' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '" class="thumbNails">';
                thumbImages = thumbImages + '"../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '_sm.jpg", ';
                $.loadImages('../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '_sm.jpg', function() {

                });
            }
        }
        thumbs = thumbs + '<div><img src="../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_1_.jpg" id="' + adID[1] + '_Preview" class="thumbNails"></div>';
        $.loadImages('../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_1_.jpg', function() {
    });


    $("#" + adID[0] + '_' + adID[1]).html(thumbs).hide();

    $("#" + adID[0] + '_' + adID[1]).slideDown('slow');
    }
});
$(this).attr("src", "../images/close_pix.png");
$(this).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
});
```

The Ajax call yields something like this "~1~2~3" depending on how many images it finds for that ad.  Then I parse through and attach the AdID to it, and preload the image.  It preloads a small thumbnail for all of the pictures, and a large preview image.

What the animation does is, especially on ones that are single images is it will do the slow animation at first and then really fast to close the animation.  I want it to slideDown smoothly at a consistent rate.

You can see the page at http://www.randykrohn.com/classifieds/allAds.php?searchKey=AllAds

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why it did that.  I copied and pasted directly from the source code of the page and when I looked at it in my editor it was correct.  Not sure why it did that.  You made a correction on the split, but it does actually split the ajax response by "~", that way it just pulls the numbers out.

Comment: Correction, the first split is now right in your correction, it is supposed to split by "_".  Copy and paste problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are not using the loadImages plug-in correctly. You are assuming that after the call to "loadImages", the images will be loaded. This won't necessarily be the case, which is why when I look at your site and hit the "show all pictures" button the first time it's very jerky. When I do it subsequent times it's smooth.Also, when I click the thumbnails the first time the transition of the current detailed image to the next is really bad, while subsequent clicks are fine.

The images will only be completely loaded when the "callback" routine is called. So, if I have a function `processImages()` that does something like animate them and call it in a way similar to how your code is written:

```
$.loadImages(['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'], function(){});
processImages();
```

This will be jerky the first time, since it is then probably being called before the images are loaded. While calling it thus:

```
$.loadImages(['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'], function(){processImages();});
```

will be nice and smooth every time, since "processImages()" will only be called when the images are loaded.

Comment: Do I have to format it as a string?  It won't work with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your comments mean, but try rewriting the code that starts:

```
    if(((images.length) - 1) > 1){
```

like this (I've visually checked it, but I may have missed something):

```
    if ((images.length > 2) {
        for (i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
            thumbs      += '<img src="../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '_sm.jpg" id="' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '" class="thumbNails">';
            thumbImages += thumbImages + '"../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '_sm.jpg", ';
            toBeLoaded[i-1] = '../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '_sm.jpg';
        }
    }
    thumbs += '<div><img src="../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_1_.jpg" id="' + adID[1] + '_Preview" class="thumbNails"></div>';
    toBeLoaded[i-1] = '../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_1_.jpg';
    $.loadImages(toBeLoaded, function(){
        $("#" + adID[0] + '_' + adID[1]).html(thumbs).hide();
        $("#" + adID[0] + '_' + adID[1]).slideDown('slow');
    });
```

i.e. load the images in a single call to loadImages and do the hiding and sliding in the callback function.

Comment: Basically I just declared toBeLoaded as new Array(); and it worked great for ads with more than 1 image, but if the ad has just one image it doesn't open anything

Comment: Hi, I couldn't quite work out why you had the code "if (((images.length) -1) > 1) {". This says "if there are 3 or more images". I think it should be "if (images.length > 1)" i.e. "if there are 2 or more images". Try that and let me know if it fixes the problem.